# How can I call a Matlab script from VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, matlab

I've written a *Matlab* **script** which it calls several functions within itself, and now I need to run it from *VB.net*. The Matlab script has no input from VB, but it has an image output and a number from the workspace.
After watching this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nO2zoRoNFiU), and reading [this page](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-a-matlab-function-from-visual-basic-net-client.html), I wrote the following code within VB.net: (In this code **main.m** is the name of Matlab script)

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Dim MatLab As Object
    Dim Result As String
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MatLab = CreateObject("Matlab.Application")
        Result = MatLab.Execute("cd D:\\main.m\")

    End Sub
End Class
```

Also, I tried to use these pages ([link 1](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getfullmatrix.html), [link 2](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getworkspacedata.html)), but they returned errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cd` stands for ***C**hange **D**irectory*. If you call `cd D:\main.m\` you're trying to navigate to a ***directory*** called `main.m` (which does not exist).

You have to do this in two steps: Change the directory first, then execute the file.

```vb
'Change directory to "D:\".
Result = MatLab.Execute("cd D:\")

'Execute "main.m".
Result = MatLab.Execute("main")
```

Comment: Dear @VisualVincent. It works (It plots the figure).Thanks a lot.
How should I get other resulting outputs (I mean the numbers)?

Comment: @Yasina : Unfortunately I don't know much about MatLab, but you should be able to save it to an image file by executing the command `saveas(gcf,'filename.png')` (ref: [how to save the content of the current figure as an image?](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/155342-how-to-save-the-content-of-the-current-figure-as-an-image#answer_152202)). You can then load that image from VB.NET.

Comment: @Yasina : Sorry, didn't notice that you edited your comment until now. As I said before I know too little about MatLab to be able to help you directly, but from a bit of searching I managed to find the following, which may or may not help you: [How do I extract data from MATLAB figures?](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100687-how-do-i-extract-data-from-matlab-figures) and: [How do I extract data points from a plot?](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100921-how-do-i-extract-data-points-from-a-plot)

Comment: Thanks. I decided to save figure and variable in the database within Matlab, and it's enough. Thanks again.

Comment: @Yasina : Glad to hear. Good luck with your project!